# I think we should block the [freeze] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-block-request

> Yes, I have found [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14878/should-we-blacklist-the-freeze-tag). *But*, it was last discussed over five years ago, and there are *still* new questions getting posted about it, so I think it is worth revisiting. Also, the linked question didn't have a conclusive answer (in my opinion).

I think the [freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze) tag should be blocked. It already says in the tag description...

> Do not use. This tag is in process of removal. If your software is freezing then you likely need to file a bug, as freeze problems are usually off topic here and will likely be closed.

But, [questions are still getting posted with it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze), despite the description saying `Do not use`. Most questions with this tag are either duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes), or are off topic, as they are bug reports (see also [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16801/are-all-freeze-related-questions-automatically-off-topic)). Therefore, I think the [freeze] tag should be blocked from being used on new questions, as it (a) it says `Do not use` in the tag description, but is still being used often and (b) is almost always off-topic or a duplicate.

Thoughts?

Comment: the process to remove the tag never happened hahaha... but I wonder if the tag isn't useful after all... similar to *overheating*

Comment: To piggyback on the comment on that question, this makes it the 5th try apparently. In  [2018](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17663) (although it was only mentioned in this question), in [2016](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14878/), in [2014](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8911), and in [2012](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3343)

Comment: @Zanna just a question... do all of the existing questioned need to be retagged _before_ the tag can be banned from use? Or can we ban it, and slowly work on the existing ones. BTW, I'd be willing to help with retagging... but it seems (from what I've looked at) that most of the questions are just duplicates or off-topic, so... thoughts on what should happen to the existing questions.

Comment: So, we very rarely blacklist tags (and only staff can do that) but it can be done without any retagging. Removing a tag from all posts that have it causes the tag to be deleted. Only users with 300+ reputation can create tags, so this generally stops tags from being used, at least for a while. When I work on removing a tag I close any questions that should be closed and so on. It's a long process.

Comment: Hmm… I see. What should be done with all of the 6000+ questions then? Retagging isn’t ideal, as many are off topic or duplicates… I’d be willing to help, but with a limit of 10 flags a day, I can’t do much.

Comment: Do note that the term was renamed from *blacklisting* to *blocking* a while back.

Comment: @gparyani good to know. I edited my post accordingly

Comment: @gparyani thanks a lot, I approve of the change!

Comment: @Zanna You might want to consider renaming the [meta-tag:tag-blacklist-request] tag to [meta-tag:tag-block-request], which you can do using the tag merge tool.

Comment: @gparyani thanks again! I've done it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we should allow the freeze tag to exist and change the usage guidance. Freezes are a common problem with some specific known causes and that can often be resolved with specific courses of action.

Since we allow people to ask about freezing problems and do not generally consider them off topic, despite the claims about that in the usage guidance, we probably need to have a tag for it.

When I attempt to retag questions that talk about this problem, I struggle to find anything appropriate - the nearest thing seems to be [performance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/performance) which is way less specific.

I propose that we fix the usage guidance, write a tag wiki linking to the canonical post about freezes, and put in some work to clean up duplicates and low quality questions in the tag.

Comment: Thoughts on what the new guidance should be? I think a start is removing DO NOT USE THIS, but more is also needed. Also, and maybe this is a separate question… do people actually read the tag descriptions?

Comment: @cocomac hmm I'll have to think about the first question... as to the second, few people read them, but they should still be there for those who do imho :)

Comment: @cocomac [how's this](https://askubuntu.com/tags/freeze/info)?

Comment: Looks amazing. Just a question… someone (maybe you?) mentioned there was a separate chat room for moderation discussion. Which one was it?

Comment: @cocomac it's [Raiders of the Lost Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat) - chat is hard to find! You may like to bookmark it.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with my fellow moderator here on an opinion basis.  The "freeze" tag is a tag that is not suitable I think for existing.  Not that questions regarding 'freezing systems" are offtopic - they should be "performance" tagged instead - but the 'freeze" tag itself is too ambiguous.  I'm a supporter of it being a blocked tag but a warning show up instead saying "If your system is freezing, use the [tag:performance] tag."